# Are there currently, or have there ever been any 'white' members of Singapore's People's Action Party(PAP)?

Tags: parties, racism, singapore

Historically, ethnicity seems to have been a sensitive issue in Singapore, one that its founding fathers have struggled with, according to various historical sources.

Today, Singapore is a successful multicultural society that attracts individuals from all over the world. This makes me curious as to whether European and North American expats in Singapore are politically active, especially within the country's largest and most dominant party.

For the purposes of this question, I mean the US definition of 'white', as used in for example Demographic and Anthropological studies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your definition of "white" is exactly, but [EW Barker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_W._Barker) and [Kenneth Michael Byrne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Michael_Byrne) were "Eurasian", so "white" by the below definition.

[US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/topics/population/race/about.html): White – A person having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East, or North Africa.